# Better approach to avoid recreating AltoRouter instance and map routes

Tags: php, singleton, altorouter

I'm using AltoRouter and works pretty well. But for every request, a new instance of AltoRouter is create and so the mapping (I followed the example from their github page).
How to avoid this overhead?
I was thinking in Singleton anti pattern. You guys think is it ok?
I have no experience with PHP.

This is code:

```
<?php

//begin of singleton
require 'AltoRouter.php';

$router = new AltoRouter();

$router->map('GET', '/', function () {        
    require '../app/home/controllers/homecontroller.php';
});
//end of singleton

$match = $router->match();

if ($match && is_callable($match['target'])) {
    call_user_func_array($match['target'], $match['params']);
} else {
    // no route was matched
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
}

?>
```

My idea is to "singletonizing" the AltoRouter instance and mapping all route only once.

Comment: _"But for every request, a new instance of AltoRouter is create"_ - That's how PHP works. Every request starts from scratch and boots up your application again. This happens with _all_ your classes and code.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. I have asp.net background. So I wrongly thought PHP works in same way.

Comment: The big difference is that .NET is compiled while PHP is interpreted at runtime. PHP handles this very well though. PHP 7 also comes bundled with a OPCode cache that enhances performance quite a bit. Just make sure it's activated. Here's a post about it: https://community.1and1.com/php-7/

Comment: @MagnusEriksson So, can I routing that way, no worries? I think your comments could be the answer.

Comment: Absolutely. If there was an issue with this, it would have been an issue with all PHP applications :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Great to here that! Thanks!